# Regular Expression for delimited email address

Tags: regex

i am looking for a regular express to validate a list of email addresses like the following

`test1@abd.com;test.test@abc.com;test3@test.com`

and

`test1@abd.com;test.test@abc.com;test3@test.com;`

optional ";" at the end of the list.

thanks,

Comment: I wish that there was a good answer for this

Comment: There is a good answer: don't use regular expressions for everything.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update**

Don't. Split on the delimiter and validate each one separately. I would also recommend setting a match timeout and/or non-backtracking flag to prevent excessive CPU usage when matching.

---

**Original Answer**

From: http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?regexp_id=1007

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+([;.](([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)*$
```

Comment: I dropped this one into Expresso and it complained that it couldnt parse it

Comment: At first glance, this will allow any number of email addresses, without any separators, followed by any number of semicolons each followed by at least one character. So this would be valid: "example@domain.comexample2@domain.com;$;8;asdf"

Comment: The entire expression did not post properly. The correct expression is on the site li ked in the post.

Comment: @Evan: it didn't post properly because you used `<code>` tags instead of SO's own formatting capabilities.  You should try to use the SO version whenever you can; it's quite good.

Comment: @Alan: Because I posted with an iPad, I did not have access to the formatting tools.

Comment: Evan: Does iPad not let you insert four spaces at the beginning of a line?  I see now that iPad is backtick-challenged, but all other SO markup can be typed in manually.  And there seem to be some workarounds for the backtick thing: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=iPad

Comment: what happen i would like to allow an optional ";" at the end of the email list?

Comment: add [;]{0,1} at the end before $ to allow optional ";" at the end of the email list.

Comment: That certainly does not look RFC compliant to me.

Comment: -1 .... this produces a mess when I test it against a@b.com at: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: i found this issue At first glance, this will allow any number of email addresses, without any separators, followed by any number of semicolons each followed by at least one character. So this would be valid: "example@domain.comexample2@domain.com;$;8;asdf" .how to fix this.any help

Comment: @NikhilVC: You may want to just split the string on a separator of your choice and validate each address individually.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski:then why would use this regex

Comment: @NikhilVC - True, I just found this error as well. To fix this, I removed the 3rd `+` sign (and the parens `()` around the first mega group), then I changed `[;.]` to a plain `;` - I actually changed that part to `;[ ]{0,1}` in case the user puts a space after the semi-colon, but this isn't necessary

Comment: @NikhilVC - I added this as [**an answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351349/regular-expression-for-delimited-email-address/48851660#48851660) below - Hopefully it works for you.

Answer (score 7):

## “You call *that* a knife???” —Crocodile Dundee

Actually, all those are very poor patterns for matching a mail address.  To  *strictly* validate an RFC 5322 mail address with *zero* false negatives and *zero* false positives, you need this precise pattern:

```
  (?x)

  (?(DEFINE)

     (?<address>         (?&mailbox) | (?&group))
     (?<mailbox>         (?&name_addr) | (?&addr_spec))
     (?<name_addr>       (?&display_name)? (?&angle_addr))
     (?<angle_addr>      (?&CFWS)? < (?&addr_spec) > (?&CFWS)?)
     (?<group>           (?&display_name) : (?:(?&mailbox_list) | (?&CFWS))? ; (?&CFWS)?)
     (?<display_name>    (?&phrase))
     (?<mailbox_list>    (?&mailbox) (?: , (?&mailbox))*)

     (?<addr_spec>       (?&local_part) \@ (?&domain))
     (?<local_part>      (?&dot_atom) | (?&quoted_string))
     (?<domain>          (?&dot_atom) | (?&domain_literal))
     (?<domain_literal>  (?&CFWS)? \[ (?: (?&FWS)? (?&dcontent))* (?&FWS)?
                                   \] (?&CFWS)?)
     (?<dcontent>        (?&dtext) | (?&quoted_pair))
     (?<dtext>           (?&NO_WS_CTL) | [\x21-\x5a\x5e-\x7e])

     (?<atext>           (?&ALPHA) | (?&DIGIT) | [!#\$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~])
     (?<atom>            (?&CFWS)? (?&atext)+ (?&CFWS)?)
     (?<dot_atom>        (?&CFWS)? (?&dot_atom_text) (?&CFWS)?)
     (?<dot_atom_text>   (?&atext)+ (?: \. (?&atext)+)*)

     (?<text>            [\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])
     (?<quoted_pair>     \\ (?&text))

     (?<qtext>           (?&NO_WS_CTL) | [\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])
     (?<qcontent>        (?&qtext) | (?&quoted_pair))
     (?<quoted_string>   (?&CFWS)? (?&DQUOTE) (?:(?&FWS)? (?&qcontent))*
                          (?&FWS)? (?&DQUOTE) (?&CFWS)?)

     (?<word>            (?&atom) | (?&quoted_string))
     (?<phrase>          (?&word)+)

     # Folding white space
     (?<FWS>             (?: (?&WSP)* (?&CRLF))? (?&WSP)+)
     (?<ctext>           (?&NO_WS_CTL) | [\x21-\x27\x2a-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])
     (?<ccontent>        (?&ctext) | (?&quoted_pair) | (?&comment))
     (?<comment>         \( (?: (?&FWS)? (?&ccontent))* (?&FWS)? \) )
     (?<CFWS>            (?: (?&FWS)? (?&comment))*
                         (?: (?:(?&FWS)? (?&comment)) | (?&FWS)))

     # No whitespace control
     (?<NO_WS_CTL>       [\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f])

     (?<ALPHA>           [A-Za-z])
     (?<DIGIT>           [0-9])
     (?<CRLF>            \x0d \x0a)
     (?<DQUOTE>          ")
     (?<WSP>             [\x20\x09])
   )

   (?&address)  # finally, match a mail address
```

I discuss this in more detail [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840988/the-recognizing-power-of-modern-regexes/4843579#4843579).

That needs a Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) library, or Perl itself, to work properly. I cannot guarantee that perl incompatible pattern engines will correctly handle the recursion.

Comment: Of course, the question was about a delimited list of email addresses...

Answer (score 6):

@Evan's answer is close, but the expression matches these scenarios which are invalid:

1. `a@test.comb@test.comc@test.com` (no delimiters)
2. `a@test.com;b@test.com.c@test.com` (period `.` accepted as delimiter)
3. `a@test.com;b@test.comc@test.com` (only 1st delimiter matched - extension of problem #1)

To fix these (and simplify a little bit), I made these changes:

1. Removed the 3rd `+` sign, and the outer parens `()` surrounding the first email address.
2. Change `[;.]` to a plain `;` delimiter - I actually changed that part to `;[ ]{0,1}` because I wanted the expression to match spaces after the semi-colon delimiter.
3. Similar to #1, remove the final `+` sign in the expression, and the outer parens `()` between the delimiter (step #2) and the final closing paren with the star after it - `)*`

Here is the final expression (allowing an optional space after the `;` delimiter:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25}(;[ ]{0,1}([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})*$/
```

Comment: I've upvoted as I found this helpful, but will be tweaking for my own use. Underscores aren't allowed in domains, so that's one tweak. The standards (and my employer) permits apostrophes in the local part, which are valid but very problematic for lots of systems, so I'm adding those too, and may also need to add support for some other of the rarer characters.

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25}(($)|( *;+ *$)|( *;+ *(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]))))*$
```

https://regexr.com/3gth7

Comment: This one actually allows for the optional semicolon at the end, as requested in the initial question. Upvote!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to allow for the presence of white space around the delimiter, so I used this modification of Evan Mulawski's answer:

`^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+(\s*[;.]\s*(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)*$`

Test it at: http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?regexp_id=13126

Answer (score -1):

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Comment: Wow, these REs are so complex, and yours more than the others here. It would help a lot of you described what you've added and how it works.

Comment: There was a web link which presumably provided background but it was edited out by a mod.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The link was the source of this Reg, but a mod removed it leaving it worst even. I agree I could have added a little description but removing information just made it worst.