# Which Method For Verification ? REGEX or filter_var?

Tags: regex, performance, security, validation, filter-var

What do you think, is there any difference (for performance, security,  reliability ) between this methods :

**METHOD 1**

```
eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)
```

**METHOD 2**

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL) 
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

Comment: What are you planning to do with the strings? If they're checked for valid email addresses, you should be aware that it is very difficult to write a working regex.

Comment: It's just an example. It's validating email. Actually, this regex pattern working very well. But i'm not sure, which method is fine.

Comment: @Tim: Difficult?  [Not really.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840988/the-recognizing-power-of-modern-regexes/4843579#4843579) You just have to follow the spec, and the pattern writes itself.

Comment: @Eray: What can you possibly mean by “security”? If security is a concern, you’ve done something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm not saying it is impossible. Also, no matter how readable your regex is, if something involves reading an RFC and writing a 20-line regex I'm not going to call it easy :) My concern though was that the regex in the original question was used to match an email address.

Comment: Method 1: "Why doesn't my email address foo@example.info work?" "Why doesn't my email address foo+bar@example.com work?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 2 is clearly easier to understand and more maintainable.  The regular expression just looks like line noise.

Comment: [Written correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840988/the-recognizing-power-of-modern-regexes/4843579#4843579), a pattern for rigorous RFC 5322 validation of mail addresses can **and should** look nothing at all like line noise. It is unprofessional to employ line noise.

Answer (score 0):

If method 2 is a good email validation then thats better.

Method 1 could be cleaned up if case insensitive to this (expanded)

**Correction:** did not read the regex close enough.

Stick with method 2 ..

Comment: Your cleaning job has been dirty! [_a-z0-9-]  which he did, can't just be replaced with \w 'cos \w doesn't include hiphen. and he wants that.  And it looks like he doesn't want underscores after the @, and he'd have them with \w