# How to use Perl Regex to detect <p> inside another <p>

Tags: regex, perl, html-parsing

I am trying to parse a "wrong html" to fix it using perl regex.
The wrong html is the following: `<p>foo<p>bar</p>foo</p>`

I would like perl regex to return me the : `<p>foo<p>`

I tried something like: `'|(<p\b[^>]*>(?!</p>)*?<p[^>]*>)|'`
with no success because I cannot repeat `(?!</p>)*?`

Is there a way in Perl Regex to say all charactère except the following sequence (in my case `</p>`)

Comment: When writing questions, you need to escape HTML/XML and code using backticks (`).

Comment: Obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @BoltClock, +1 and the response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840988/the-recognizing-power-of-modern-regexes it's impressive what a modern regex can match, if you can be bothered writing one ;)

Comment: @Obligatory: Please don't use that link any more.  It is confusing to beginners, and only clever to those who understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
<p>(?:(?!</?p>).)*</p>(?!(?:(?!</?p>).)*(<p>|$))
```

A quick break down:

```
<p>(?:(?!</?p>).)*</p>
```

matches `<p> ... </p>` that does **not** contain either `<p>` and `</p>`. And the part:

```
(?!(?:(?!</?p>).)*(<p>|$))
```

is "true" when looking ahead (`(?! ... )`) there is no `<p>` or the end of the input (`(<p>|$)`), without any `<p>` and `</p>` in between (`(?:(?!</?p>).)*`).

A demo:

```
my $txt="<p>aaa aa a</p> <p>foo <p>bar</p> foo</p> <p> bb <p>x</p> bb</p>";
while($txt =~ m/(<p>(?:(?!<\/?p>).)*<\/p>)(?!(?:(?!<\/?p>).)*(<p>|$))/g) {
  print "Found: $1\n";
}
```

prints:

```
Found: <p>bar</p>
Found: <p>x</p>
```

Note that this regex trickery only works for `<p>baz</p>` in the string:

```
<p>foo <p>bar</p> <p>baz</p> foo</p>
```

`<p>bar</p>` is not matched! After replacing `<p>baz</p>`, you could do a 2nd run on the input, in which case `<p>bar</p>` will be matched.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help :) Based on your solution, I tried also: `|(<p\b[^>]*>(?:(?!</p>).)*<p[^>]*>)|`  seems to works correctly, is there something wrong that I should use your solution ?

Comment: @Tompap, but that matches `<p>foo<p>` from your string `<p>foo<p>bar</p>foo</p>`...

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Andy.  Parsing nontrivial HTML with regexps is a world of pain.

Have a good look at HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath and HTML::DOM for making structural changes to HTML documents.

Comment: It looks like DOM and TreeBuilder both 'correct' your HTML as they parse it.  Which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This regexp:

```
<p>(?:(?!</p>).)*?<p>
```

when matched with

```
<p>foo<p>bar</p>foo</p>
```

results in

```
<p>foo<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to validate HTML then consider a module like [HTML::Tidy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Tidy) or [HTML::Lint](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Lint).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [`Marpa::HTML`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Marpa-HTML/) would help you. Read some interesting abilities it has on the [author's blog about it](http://blogs.perl.org/users/jeffrey_kegler/2010/03/an-html-pretty-printer.html). The short of it is that the parser works with the interpreter (I probably am getting some of the semantics incorrect) to figure out what should be present based on what CAN be present at a certain logical place in the code.

The examples shown therein fix similar problems as you seem to be dealing with in a much more consistent way than employing regexes which will inevitably suffer from edge cases.

`Marpa::HTML` comes with a command-line utility, built using the module, called `html_fmt`. This implements a parsing engine to fix and pretty-print html. Here is an example. If 'bad.html' contains `<p>foo<p>bar</p>foo</p>` then `html_fmt bad.html` gives:

```
<!-- Following start tag is replacement for a missing one -->
<html>
  <!-- Following start tag is replacement for a missing one -->
  <head>
  </head>
  <!-- Preceding end tag is replacement for a missing one -->
  <!-- Following start tag is replacement for a missing one -->
  <body>
    <p>
      foo
    </p>
    <!-- Preceding end tag is replacement for a missing one -->
    <p>
      bar
    </p>
    foo
    <!-- Next line is cruft -->
    </p>
  </body>
  <!-- Preceding end tag is replacement for a missing one -->
</html>
<!-- Preceding end tag is replacement for a missing one -->
```