# How the Perl regular expressions dialect/implementation is called?

Tags: regex, perl, theory, finite-automata, recursive-descent

The engine for parsing strings which is called "regular expressions" in Perl is very different from what is known by the term "regular expressions" in books.

So, my question is: is there some document describing the Perl's regexp implementation and how and in what ways does it really differ from the classic one (by classic I mean a regular expressions that can really be transformed to ordinary DFA/NFA) and how it works?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl regular expressions are of course called Perl regular expressions, or regexes for short. They may also be called patterns or rules. But what they *are,* or at least **can be,** is [recursive descent parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840988/the-recognizing-power-of-modern-regexes/4843579#4843579). They’re implemented using a recursive backtracker, although you can swap in a [DFA engine](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?re::engine::RE2) if you prefer to offload DFA‐solvable tasks to it.

Here are some relevant citations about these matters, with all emboldening — and some of the text :) — mine:

> You specify a pattern by creating a *regular expression* (or *regex*),
>   and Perl’s regular expression engine (the “Engine”, for the rest of this
>   chapter) then takes that expression and determines whether (and how) the
>   pattern matches your data.  While most of your data will probably be
>   text strings, there’s nothing stopping you from using regexes to search
>   and replace any byte sequence, even what you’d normally think of as
>   “binary” data.  To Perl, bytes are just characters that happen to have
>   an ordinal value less than 256.
>
> **If you’re acquainted with regular expressions from some other venue, we
>   should warn you that regular expressions are a bit different in Perl.
>   First, they aren’t entirely “regular” in the theoretical sense of the
>   word, which means they can do much more than the traditional regular
>   expressions taught in computer science classes.**  Second, they are used
>   so often in Perl that they have their own special variables, operators,
>   and quoting conventions which are tightly integrated into the language,
>   not just loosely bolted on like any other library.

— [*Programming Perl*](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004927/), by Larry Wall, Tom Christiansen, and Jon Orwant

> This is the Apocalypse on Pattern Matching, generally having to do with
>   **what we call “regular expressions”, which are only marginally related to
>   real regular expressions.** Nevertheless, the term has grown with the
>   capabilities of our pattern matching engines, so I’m not going to try to
>   fight linguistic necessity here. I will, however, generally call them
>   “regexes” (or “regexen”, when I’m in an Anglo‐Saxon mood).

— [Perl6 Apocalypse 5: Pattern Matching](http://dev.perl.org/perl6/doc/design/apo/A05.html), by Larry Wall

> There’s a lot of new syntax there, so let’s step through it slowly, starting with:

```
    $file = rx/ ^  <$hunk>*  $ /;
```

> This statement creates a pattern object. Or, as it’s known in Perl 6, a
>   “rule”. People will probably still call them “regular expressions” or
>   “regexes” too (and the keyword `rx` reflects that), but **Perl patterns long
>   ago ceased being anything like “regular”,** so we’ll try and avoid those
>   terms.
>
> [Update: We’ve resurrected the term “regex” to refer to these patterns in
>   general. When we say “rule” now, we’re specifically referring to the kind
>   of regex that you would use in a grammar. See S05.]

— [Perl6 Exegesis 5: Pattern Matching](http://dev.perl.org/perl6/doc/design/exe/E05.html), by Damian Conway

> This document summarizes Apocalypse 5, which is about the new regex syntax.
>   **We now try to call them *regex* rather than “regular expressions” because
>   they haven’t been regular expressions for a long time, and we think the
>   popular term “regex” is in the process of becoming a technical term with a
>   precise meaning of: “something you do pattern matching with, kinda like a regular
>   expression”.** On the other hand, one of the purposes of the redesign
>   is to make portions of our patterns more amenable to analysis under
>   traditional regular expression and parser semantics, and that involves
>   making careful distinctions between which parts of our patterns and
>   grammars are to be treated as declarative, and which parts as procedural.
>
> In any case, when referring to recursive patterns within a grammar, the
>   terms *rule* and *token* are generally preferred over *regex*.

— [Perl6 Synopsis 5: Regexes and Rules](http://feather.perl6.nl/syn/S05.html),
by Damian Conway, Allison Randal, Patrick Michaud, Larry Wall, and Moritz Lenz

Answer (score 4):

The O'Reilly book ['Mastering Regular Expressions'](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528126/) has a very good explanation of Perl's and other engines. For me this is the reference book on the topic.

Comment: MRE is now in its third edition (link updated), and still the one absolutely indispensable book on regexes.

Comment: Thanks for the info Alan. I must have a look at it!

Answer (score 2):

There is no formal mathematical name for the language accepted by PCREs.

The term "regular expressions with [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Implementations_and_running_times)" or "regular expressions with backreferences" is about as close as you will get.  Anybody familiar with the difference will know what you mean.

(There are only two common types of regexp implementations:  DFA-based, and backtracking-based.  The former generally accept the "regular languages" in the traditional Computer Science sense.  The latter generally accept...  More, and it depends on the specific implementation, but backreferences are always one the non-DFA features.)

Answer (score 2):

I asked the same question on the theoretical CS Stack Exchange ([Regular expressions aren't](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/448/regular-expressions-arent)), and the [answer that got the most upvotes](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/448/regular-expressions-arent/486#486) was “regex.”

Answer (score -2):

- The dialect is called PCRE (Perl-compatible Regular Expressions).
- It's documented in the [Perl manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).
- Or in "Programming Perl" by Wall, Orwant and Christiansen

Comment: PCRE has never been entirely Perl-compatible.

Comment: PCRE is NOT the Perl Regex Engine. Just from the name (Perl-Compatible) you should recognize that PCRE is not the Perl regex engine. PCRE is an independent engine. Perl regexes are a lot more powerful than those of PCRE.

Comment: My understanding was that PCRE mirrored the Perl regex library, only that they didn't go with the more recent changes in Perl (so maybe reflecting Perl 5.6 or 5.8).

Comment: PCRE is mostly 5.10, but with supermarginal Unicode property support.