# Detect opening and closing brackets

Tags: ruby, regex

From a string:

```
"(book(1:3000))"
```

I need to exclude opening and closing brackets and match:

```
"book(1:3000)"
```

using regular expression.

I tried this regular expression:

```
/([^',()]+)|'([^']*)'/
```

which detects all characters and integers excluding brackets. The string detected by this regex is:

```
"book 1:3000"
```

Is there any regex that disregards the opening and closing brackets, and gives the entire string?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:ruby-on-rails]?

Comment: @Amadan in a hope Rails provides some magic, like a dedicated method doing exactly that?

Comment: It would probably help if you could provide some _context_. For example, what does that string represent, where does it come from, what is `book(...)` (looks like a function call), what is `1:3000`, what's the pattern that you want to match (explain it or show some examples), is there always an additional pair of parentheses surrounding the substring you're interested in?

Comment: instead of regex black magic, you could just do `new_str = str[1..-2]` or maybe `new_str = str.start_with?('(') ? str[1..-2] : str` if that is what your data consistently looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Build the regexp that explicitly states exactly what you want to extract: alphanumerics, followed by the opening parenthesis, followed by digits, followed by a colon, followed by digits, followed by closing parenthesis:

```
'(book(1:3000))'[/\w+\(\d+:\d+\)/]
#⇒ "book(1:3000)"
```

Comment: No Sir, It is not working. Here is the link `http://rubular.com/r/RipuLVfSXy` for the tested `regex`.

Comment: Sure it works. The link contains some crap that has nothing to do with a regexp I provided.

Comment: @ThananjayaChakravarthy the square brackets belong to the [method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), not the regexp. It's `str[regexp]` with `str` being `'(book(1:3000))'` and `regexp` being `/\w+\(\d+:\d+\)/`. Here's a working example: http://rubular.com/r/7UpYX5ijQS

Answer (score 2):

```
"(book(1:3000))"[/^\(?(.+?\))\)?/, 1]
=> "book(1:3000)"
"book(1:3000)"[/^\(?(.+?\))\)?/, 1]
=> "book(1:3000)"
```

The regex split on multiple lines for easier reading:

```
/
 ^      # start of string
  \(?   # character (, possibly (?)
  (     # start capturing
    .+? # any characters forward until..
    \)  # ..a closing bracket
  )     # stop capturing
/x      # end regex with /x modifier (allows splitting to lines)
```

1. Look for a possible `(` in the beginning of string and ignore it.
 2. Start capturing
 3. Capture until and including the first `)`

But this is where it fails:

```
"book(1:(10*30))"[/^\(?(.+?\))\)?/, 1]
=> "book(1:(10*30)"
```

If you need something like that, you probably need to use a recursive regex as 
described in [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6331667/681520).