# Is it possible to replace div contents with regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, replace

Is it possible to write a regular expression to replace everything between `<div id=”somevalue123” class=”text-block”>` and `</div>`? I can do this but the problem I am having is that there are other div nodes within the string.

Here is the current regular expression that I am using:

```
public static function replaceStringBetween($start, $end, $new, $source, $limit = 1)
{
    // Reinitialize the replacement count
    self::$replacement_count = 0;

    // Try to perform the replacement
    $result = preg_replace('#('.preg_quote($start) . ')(.*)('.preg_quote($end) 
        . ')#is', '$1' . $new . '$3', $source, $limit, $count);
    if ($count > 0)
    {
        self::$replacement_count++;
        return $result;
    }

    // As a fallback, try again with a different method
    $result = preg_replace ("#{$start}(.*){$end}#is", $new, $source, $limit, $count);
    if ($count > 0)
    {
        self::$replacement_count++;
        return $result;
    }

    // Return the original
    return $source;
}
```

I am passing an HTML file as the source, of course.
Thanks

Comment: You're better off with a proper XML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are not capable of supporting arbitrary nesting. You may want to consider a push-down automaton (parser) for arbitrary nesting.

In practice, you could design a series of regular expressions to parse a fixed number of these. However, once you start getting into handling error conditions and (parse) errors, you are really trying to shoe horn a regular expression into the place of a parser.

This seems like you may want to reconsider your approach and design in the modularity you seek, rather than putting it in after the fact by using a regular expression bait-and-switch.

Comment: Modern "regexes" are perfectly capable of supporting arbitrary nested.  I wish these lies would stop being propagated.

Comment: Can you show me an example? I am not intentionally trying to propagate untruths. I remember this from my formal languages and automata class four years ago.

Comment: [Here’s an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840988/the-recognizing-power-of-modern-regexes/4843579#4843579) for you.

Comment: Thanks. The next time I need to implement capture on something with arbitrary nesting, I am going to try and use a modern regex.

Answer (score 2):

A simple to use PHP parser which I have used to do exactly this in the past is the [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). You would use the selector `div#somevalue123`.