# Parsing "From:" field of an e-mail message in Python

Tags: python, email

I am trying to parse an [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) compliant "From: " field in an e-mail message into two parts: the display-name, and the e-mail address, in Python 2.7 (the display-name could be empty).  The familiar example is something like

```
John Smith <jsmith@example.org>
```

In above, John Smith is the display-name and jsmith@example.org is the email address. But the following is also a valid "From: " field:

```
"unusual" <"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com>
```

In this example, the return value for display-name is

```
"unusual"
```

and

```
"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com
```

is the email address.

You can use grammars to parse this in Perl (as explained in these questions: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1917982/765195) and [The recognizing power of “modern” regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4843579/765195)), but I'd like to do this in Python 2.7. I have tried using email.parser module in Python, but that module seems only to be able to separate those fields that are distinguished by a colon. So, if you do something like

```
from email.parser import Parser
headers = Parser().parsestr('From: "John Smith" <jsmith@example.org>')
print headers['from']
```

it will return

```
"John Smith" <jsmith@example.com>
```

while if you replace the last line in the above code with

```
print headers['display-name']
```

it will return

```
None
```

I'll very much appreciate any suggestions and comments.

Comment: I'd suggest getting it to work? You need to give more information about the problem before anyone can give more specific help.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: The `headers['display-name']` does not make sense. The display-name is not a field of the header, but of the 1st email address in the From: ... header.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`headers['display-name']` is not part of the `email.parser` api.

Try email.utils.parseaddr:

```
In [17]: email.utils.parseaddr("jsmith@example.com")
Out[17]: ('', 'jsmith@example.com')

In [18]: email.utils.parseaddr("(John Smith) jsmith@example.com")
Out[18]: ('John Smith', 'jsmith@example.com')

In [19]: email.utils.parseaddr("John Smith <jsmith@example.com>")
Out[19]: ('John Smith', 'jsmith@example.com')
```

It also handles your unusual address:

```
In [21]: email.utils.parseaddr('''"unusual" <"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com>''')
Out[21]: ('unusual', '"very.(),:;<>[]".VERY."very@ "very".unusual"@strange.example.com')
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect! It's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote such a parser in [libtld](http://snapwebsites.org/project/libtld) in C++. If you want to really be complete, there is the lex and yacc (although I do not use those tools). My [C++ code](http://snapwebsites.org/mo_references_view/libtld-doc-1.4/tld__emails_8cpp_source.html) may help you write your own version in python.

```
(lex part)
[-A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]+                                          atom_text_repeat (ALPHA+DIGIT+some other characters)
([\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x27\x2A-\x5B\x5D-\x7E]|\\[\x09\x20-\x7E])+           comment_text_repeat
([\x33-\x5A\x5E-\x7E])+                                                  domain_text_repeat
([\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7E]|\\[\x09\x20-\x7E])+                            quoted_text_repeat
\x22                                                                     DQUOTE
[\x20\x09]*\x0D\x0A[\x20\x09]+                                           FWS
.                                                                        any other character

(lex definitions merged in more complex lex definitions)
[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F]                                         NO_WS_CTL
[()<>[\]:;@\\,.]                                                         specials
[\x01-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x7F]                                             text
\\[\x09\x20-\x7E]                                                        quoted_pair ('\\' text)
[A-Za-z]                                                                 ALPHA
[0-9]                                                                    DIGIT
[\x20\x09]                                                               WSP
\x20                                                                     SP
\x09                                                                     HTAB
\x0D\x0A                                                                 CRLF
\x0D                                                                     CR
\x0A                                                                     LF

(yacc part)
address_list: address
            | address ',' address_list
address: mailbox
       | group
mailbox_list: mailbox
            | mailbox ',' mailbox_list
mailbox: name_addr
       | addr_spec
group: display_name ':' mailbox_list ';' CFWS
     | display_name ':' CFWS ';' CFWS
name_addr: angle_addr
         | display_name angle_addr
display_name: phrase
angle_addr: CFWS '<' addr_spec '>' CFWS
addr_spec: local_part '@' domain
local_part: dot_atom
          | quoted_string
domain: dot_atom
      | domain_literal
domain_literal: CFWS '[' FWS domain_text_repeat FWS ']' CFWS
phrase: word
      | word phrase
word: atom
    | quoted_string
atom: CFWS atom_text_repeat CFWS
dot_atom: CFWS dot_atom_text CFWS
dot_atom_text: atom_text_repeat
             | atom_text_repeat '.' dot_atom_text
quoted_string: CFWS DQUOTE quoted_text_repeat DQUOTE CFWS
CFWS: <empty>
    | FWS comment
    | CFWS comment FWS
comment: '(' comment_content ')'
comment_content: comment_text_repeat
               | comment
               | ccontent ccontent
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to avoid writing a parser.

Comment: Ah! It wasn't clear in the question that you did not want to write the actual parser. 8-)