# Regex to include multiple EmailIds in Java

Tags: java, regex, email

I have a requirement where I send multiple emails to client.

But I have a issue while sending email to multiple email Ids.

For example, if I write

```
s@t.com;r@t.com
```

It would throw me an error stating email id is not correct.

I want the email ids to be separated by semicolon but it seems my regex is not supporting semicolons.

Proper format should be :

```
s@t.com;d@r.com
```

Should not allow

```
s;r@t.com
```

Regex used

```
myregex = "^['_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"
```

Please guide.

Comment: Why not simple `string.split(";")`

Comment: How do you send the emails? You should probably split the emails on the `:` and set multiple recipients.

Comment: Actually we have set in our JPA class for the field using @Pattern

Comment: so i need to have a format to include ; after an email id. No other options.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809357/regex-for-validating-multiple-e-mail-addresses

Comment: You have a regex for 1 email, right? You want to check if the string contains email + ( `;` + email ) {any number of times}, right? Then, use the `myregex = "['_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})"; String final_pattern = regex + "(?:;" + regex + ")*";`. Note the `^` and `$` are removed from the `regex` pattern.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: Guys, this is not a dupe question for validating emails. OP has a regex for that, and only needs to make sure multiple semicolon separated emails  get through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a regex for 1 email.

Now, you want to check if the string contains `email` + ( `;` + `email` ) *{any number of times}*.

You need to use your previous pattern as a block without anchors and build the  final pattern like this:

```
String myregex = "['_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(?:\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(?:\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"; 
String final_pattern = "\\A" + regex + "(?:;" + regex + ")*" + "\\z";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZ2iX1/1)

Note that `\A` is the *unambiguous* start of string and `\z` - the *very* end of string anchors.

Also note that the `+` inside a character class loses its special meaning of a quantifier (*1 or more times*), and becomes/is treated as a mere literal `+`  symbol. I also removed unnecessary groupings and turned all capturing groups into non-capturing for a "cleaner" matching (if you need no captured values, why store them in a stack for each group?).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you use string.split("_"); you will be fine. I used for mine bodyremoveregex=(ÎÎÎÎÎ£ On Line)([,]* [0-9]*:[0-9]*, [0-9]*/[0-9]*)*__(/**/) and it worked correctly.You just have to add _ between the expressions.For some reason it doesn't show the _ symbol in my answer so imagine that everywhere I have __ I mean _.

Comment: You should enclose `code` with backticks (`\``code`\``), then it will display "raw" text.