# Custom data annotation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have added the below custom data annotation validation in my code for my text area (*to allow only valid email IDs*)

```
 public class ValidateEmails : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            string[] commaLst = value.ToString().Split(',');
            foreach (var item in commaLst)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress email = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(item.ToString().Trim());

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid email IDs separated by commas;");
                }
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

}
```

Model:

```
 public class BuildModel
{
    public Int64 ConfigID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a stream!")]
    public string StreamName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a build location!")]
    public string BuildLocation { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public bool IsCoverity { get; set; }

    [ValidateEmails(ErrorMessage = "NOT VALID !!!")]
    public string EmailIDsForCoverity { get; set; }
   }
```

When I run my app and enter an invalid string in the text area, the breakpoint hits inside the validation. But however, the submit action goes on to happen.

Actually, I have a bootstrap modal form, within which I do the validation. On click of submit button, the inbuilt custom validations like 'Required' work well. However, my custom data annotation validation won't work. What wrong am I doing here?

Comment: Are you checking for `Model.IsValid` in your action?

Comment: you can use `RegularExpression` validators for this and regex for this comma separated validation is `(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)(\s*;\s*|\s*$))*
` please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9809636/2534646) for more info

Comment: Your attribute needs to implement `IClientValidatable` and you need to write the scripts to add the rules  to the `$.validator` if you want client side validation.

Comment: Any examples or demo?

Comment: Just use data type attributes to validate your field , mvc has an inbuilt one

Answer (score 0):

You should check `Model.IsValid` value in controller. `Model.IsValid` return `false` if any validation fails(including custom validations). So your controller's code look like below.

```
  [HttpPost]
  public virtual ActionResult Index(BuildModel viewModel)
  {

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      // Your Custom code...
    }

    return View(viewModel);
  }
```

Comment: But I need it to be validated at client side only.

Comment: Then you should use jquery validation. Custom validation work on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look similar to this:

```
[Display(Name = "Email address")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Source : [Email address validation using ASP.NET MVC data type attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712043/email-address-validation-using-asp-net-mvc-data-type-attributes)

Comment: My input would be comma separated e-mail IDs, not a single email ID.